# Changing Values in recyclerview when menu item changes in menu list

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, popup, menuitem, data-conversion

i am building unit converter app...so when unit from popup change my values in recycler view donnot change suddenly..but values change when i change value in input according to selected unit..i want to change my recyclerview values when unit change in popup menu....

```
enter code here
```

class LengthFragment : Fragment() {
lateinit var adapter: LengthAdapter
private var currentUnit: String = DataServices.units[0].title
private lateinit var binding: FragmentLengthBinding
override fun onCreateView(
inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
binding = FragmentLengthBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
binding.inputValue.setMaxLength(10)
binding.inputValue.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {

```
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {}

        override fun beforeTextChanged(
            s: CharSequence, start: Int,
            count: Int, after: Int
        ) {
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            calculateNewValues(s.toString(), adapter.units)
        }
    })

    adapter = LengthAdapter(context, DataServices.units)
    binding.unitsListView.adapter = adapter
    val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    layoutManager.also { binding.unitsListView.layoutManager = it }
    binding.unitsListView.setHasFixedSize(true)

    binding.showPopUp.setOnClickListener {
        val popup = PopupMenu(context, showPopUp)
        popup.inflate(R.menu.test)
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
            currentUnit = it.title.toString()
            showPopUp.text = currentUnit
            true
        }
        popup.show()
    }
    return binding.root
}
private fun EditText.setMaxLength(maxLength: Int) {
    filters = arrayOf<InputFilter>(InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength))

}
private  fun calculateNewValues(inputValue: String, newList: List<Units>) {
    if (inputValue.isNotEmpty() && inputValue.isNotBlank()) {
        val currentValue = when (currentUnit) {
            "um" -> inputValue.toDouble().um2m()
            "mm" -> inputValue.toDouble().mm2m()
            "cm" -> inputValue.toDouble().cm2m()
            "dm" -> inputValue.toDouble().dm2m()
            "m" -> inputValue.toDouble().m2m()
            "inch" -> inputValue.toDouble().inch2m()
            "ft" -> inputValue.toDouble().ft2m()
            "yard" -> inputValue.toDouble().yd2m()
            "mile" -> inputValue.toDouble().mile2m()
            "km" -> inputValue.toDouble().km2m()
            "NM" -> inputValue.toDouble().NM2m()
            else -> 0.0
        }
        for (u in newList) {
            u.value = when (u.title) {
                "um" -> currentValue.m2um()
                "mm" -> currentValue.m2mm()
                "cm" -> currentValue.m2cm()
                "dm" -> currentValue.m2dm()
                "m" -> currentValue.m2m()
                "inch" -> currentValue.m2inch()
                "ft" -> currentValue.m2ft()
                "yard" -> currentValue.m2yd()
                "mile" -> currentValue.m2mile()
                "km" -> currentValue.m2km()
                "NM" -> currentValue.m2NM()
                else -> 0.0
            }
            Log.d("newList", "${u.title} :: ${u.value}")
        }
    }
    if (inputValue.isEmpty() && inputValue.isBlank()) {
        for (u in newList) {
            u.value = 0.0
        }

    }
    adapter.dataSet(newList)
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

}

Comment: call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after you change the unit from popup